# Getting Connection reset for Maven dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

Getting below error for the following POM. Code get build locally and executes fine.
But get below exception in Jenking build. Please suggest.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.1.1:jar (default-jar) on
> project app-profile: Execution default-jar of goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.1.1:jar failed: Plugin
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.1.1 or one of its
> dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:3.1.1 ->
> org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:3.3.0: Failed to read artifact
> descriptor for org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:3.3.0: Could not
> transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:3.3.0 from/to
> central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset ->
> [Help 1]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-someApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <docker.image.prefix>springio</docker.image.prefix>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <!--SonarQube properties -->
        <sonar.projectName>test-app-someApp</sonar.projectName>
        <sonar.projectVersion>1.0</sonar.projectVersion>
        <sonar.scm.provider>git</sonar.scm.provider>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportMissing.force.zero>true</sonar.jacoco.reportMissing.force.zero>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/main/generated</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>someClass.class</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>com/generated/**/*</excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0.905</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                    <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Greenwich.SR6</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wsd.common.utilities</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsd-java-common-utilities</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.joschi.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.newrelic.agent.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>newrelic-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-new-relic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JAXB Binders to suppress a bug in Spring Release 2.0.0; Consider removing 
            these as it may get fixed in newer Spring releases -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JAXB Binders to suppress a bug in Spring Release 2.0.0; Consider removing 
            these as it may get fixed in newer Spring releases -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sns</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dlq.wsd.ntr.sharedlibrary</groupId>
            <artifactId>ntr-web-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dlq.wsd.ntr.sharedlibrary</groupId>
            <artifactId>ntr-logmanager-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>llp-java-common-utilities</id>
            <url>http://internal.com/artifactory/ntr-java-common-utilities</url>
        </repository>
        <repository><!-- Common utilities -->
            <id>apps-release-local</id>
            <url>http://internal.com/artifactory/apps-release-local</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Network `from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset` issue... proxy / firewall ? ...

Comment: let me check with my DevOps, as it run fine some times, 1 out of 10 times. just want to be sure, if my maven plugins and dependencies are not unmatching or something like that. In that case it should have never worked but still, I have tried and googled most of the possibilites.

Comment: In the end you need to fix your network connections...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Maven repo was unreachable many a times, reason could be any, network or porxy.
So DevOps team set up our own repo which we used to refer our dependencies.

it fixed the issue. Instead of maven repo we now use our Repo.